# How can I achieve to implement the below query without the if statement (SUM/AVG)?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, design-patterns, group-by, linq-expressions

```
public class DailyAggregator : Aggregator
{
    public override Dictionary<string, int?> Aggregate<T>(IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> groupByProperty, Expression<Func<T, double>> operationProperty = null)
    {
        if (operationProperty == null) // property of sum/avg (null = count)
            operationProperty = x => 1;

        if (_operationType.Equals(ReportAggregationOperation.Sum))
        {
            return query
                .GroupBy(g => new
                {
                    Day = TestableDbFunctions.TruncateTime(groupByProperty.Invoke(g))
                })
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Key = x.Key.Day.ToString().Substring(0, 10),
                    Value = (int?) x.Sum(operationProperty.Compile()),
                })
                .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            return query
               .GroupBy(g => new
               {
                   Day = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(groupByProperty.Invoke(g))
               })
               .Select(
                x => new
                {
                    Key = x.Key.Day.ToString().Substring(0, 10),
                    Value = (int?) x.Average(operationProperty.Compile()),
                }).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using an IOC container for creating instances like dailyaggreagtor/monthlyaggregator...
But I wasn't able to build this group by expression, or to apply the right design pattern to eliminate the above if statement.

The compile and invoke functions comes from the LinqKit extension. 
The classes using this aggregator(s) is querying the DB and collecting data for callcenter reports (ex. TotalCdrRecords report, ReachedCdrRecords report, CdrTalkTime report, CdrCallAfterworkTime etc., a CDR is a call data record, practically holding all information about a call). The type of the query (T) is specified in the report classes, but basically is an IReportableEntity, but of course the operationProperty it can be any property of the DB Entity which we can perfom the count/sum/avg operations, the groupByProperty is always a DateTime column.

It generates the following sql query:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
SUBSTRING(CASE WHEN ([GroupBy1].[K1] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE  CAST( [GroupBy1].[K1] AS nvarchar(max)) END, 0 + 1, 10) AS [C2], 
 CAST( [GroupBy1].[A1] AS int) AS [C3]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1], 
    SUM([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[CreatedOn], 102) ,  102) AS [K1], 
        cast(1 as float(53)) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[VCCCdr] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[CreatedOn] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[CreatedOn] <= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[CompanyId] = @p__linq__2)
    )  AS [Filter1]
    GROUP BY [K1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Comment: From curiosity, does it work at all the way it's written? But constructively, there are too many missing information in order to get meaningful answer - the type of `query`, `groupBy` , `operationProperty` variables, the usage of `Invoke` and `Compile` (LINQKit?) etc.

Comment: Yes it work except the tostring part, but I edited the post. And yes the compile and invoke is part of the LinqKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using LINQKit, you can extract an expression for calling `Sum` / `Average` part and `Invoke` it inside the query.

For instance:

```
var aggregateFunc = _operationType.Equals(ReportAggregationOperation.Sum) ?
        Linq.Expr((IEnumerable<double> source) => source.Sum()) :
        Linq.Expr((IEnumerable<double> source) => source.Average());

return query
    .GroupBy(g => new
    {
        Day = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(groupByProperty.Invoke(g))
    })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Key = x.Key.Day.ToString().Substring(0, 10),
        Value = (int?)aggregateFunc.Invoke(x.Select(operationProperty.Compile())),
    })
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
```

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you very much! I hope this will be usefull for others to, because I didn't found similar questions about extracting a part of the group by expression